# Is there a way to use a TEXTJOIN and increment the delimiter?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a number of cells I want to join together in a URL. The first part is relatively easy using TEXTJOIN because the delimiter is always the same. The second part is trickier. The parameters get incrementally larger and there is a chance some may be skipped over. Here is the code I started with where everything is spelled out individually.

```
=$C$1&IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("~?",$C$1)),"&","?")&IF($C$3<>"","cm_mmc="&$C$3,"")&IF($C$4<>"","-_-"&$C$4,"")&IF($C$5<>"","-_-"&$C$5,"")&IF($C$6<>"","-_-"&$C$6,"")&IF($C$7<>"","&a1="&$C$7,"")&IF($C$8<>"","&a2="&$C$8,"")&IF($C$9<>"","&a3="&$C$9,"")&IF($C$10<>"","&a4="&$C$10,"")
```

I was able to simplify the first part to this.

```
=$C$1&IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("~?",$C$1)),"&","?")&"cm_mmc="&TEXTJOIN("-_-",TRUE,$C$3:$C$6)&IF($C$7<>"","&a1="&$C$7,"")&IF($C$8<>"","&a2="&$C$8,"")&IF($C$9<>"","&a3="&$C$9,"")&IF($C$10<>"","&a4="&$C$10,"")
```

What I need to figure out is how to use a TEXTJOIN to continue adding cells but have that delimiter (a1, a2, a3,...) increase even if one of the parameters is blank.

Can this be done?

Comment: Can you share some sample strings (and desired output) to help demonstrate what the formula should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the last part can be done:

```
"&a"&TEXTJOIN("&a",TRUE,IF($C$7:$C$10<>"",ROW($1:$4)&"="&$C$7:$C$10,""))
```

The `ROW($1:$4)` places the correct number in the sequence, Make the number of rows match the number of cells to join.

so:

```
=$C$1&IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("~?",$C$1)),"&","?")&"cm_mmc="&=TEXTJOIN("-_-",TRUE,$C$3:$C$6)&"&a"&TEXTJOIN("&a",TRUE,IF($C$7:$C$10<>"",ROW($1:$4)&"="&$C$7:$C$10,""))
```

[image]

Comment: What if a row is skipped. For example no value is entered and the "6" is blank. Will the next number still be "7"?

Comment: Did you test it?  It should

Comment: Did you use ctrl-shift-enter instead of enter when exiting edit mode?

Comment: Actually I didn't. Wasn't aware of that but it now works. What does that do? I need to read up on this.

Comment: It forces it into an array formula.  Office 365 subscription has done away with that need.  But any other version will require it.

Comment: Oh. Interesting. I thought I was actually running Office 365. Now I need to look.
Would something like this also work in Google Sheets?

Comment: Possibly, not sure though.  You would have to test.

Comment: FYI. You can import the Excel spreadsheet into Google Sheets and it translates it so that it works.

Comment: This is interesting. If I do not have a value in any of those  cells(C7:C10) then the end of my URL ends with '&a' . Not ideal. Ideally there would be nothing if no additional values were chosen. Option 2 would be '&a='